# String comparison for equality in an object array: unexpected false

Tags: c#

Consider the following:

```
using System;

namespace ObjectArrayWeirdness
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static object[] Change(object[] set)
        {
            object[] result = new object[set.Length];

            // If the following two lines are replaced with:
            // result[0] = "ab";
            // then ArrayEquals will evaluate true.
            result[0] = "a";
            result[0] += "b";
            return result;
        }

        public static bool ArrayEquals(object[] a, object[] b)
        {
            if (a.Length != b.Length) return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] != b[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] expected = { "ab" };
            object[] actual = Change(new object[] { 1 });
            Console.WriteLine(ArrayEquals(expected, actual));
        }
    }
}
```

[Dotnetfiddle for convenience](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yLS8eo)

Output:

```
false
```

Output of `result[0].GetType()`:

```
System.String
```

My questions:

1. Does the comparison in `ArrayEquals` fail because it's comparing object reference and not value?
2. If that's the case, why does it succeed when the correct string is assigned in one step (without using `+=`) into `result[0]`?

I must admit I expected normal string comparison given that `GetType()` identifies both `a[0]` and `b[0]` as strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the comparison in ArrayEquals fail because it's comparing object reference and not value?

Yes

> If that's the case, why does it succeed when the correct string is assigned in one step (without using +=) into result[0]?

This is a compiler optimization.  When you declare two literal strings that are the same at compile time, the compiler collapses them into a single object instance to save space.  But if the string is constructed at run time, you'll end up with two separate string objects.

Answer (score 1):

That exactly what happens. You are comparing object reference. Note however that string overrides the `==` and `!=` operators to compare literals. So your comparison will work as you expect it if you cast the array items to string:

```
if ((string)a[i] != (string)b[i])
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'd added `.ToString()` in subsequent code, just wanted to be clear on what was happening.

Comment: Yes, I agree understanding the source of the problem is way more important then just solving it. And @JohnWu gives good and clear explanation of what actually happens.